Packaging war using proguard with spring-boot-maven-plugin, there is no obfuscated classes in output war
I tried to obfuscate my spring boot project with proguard and proguard-maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin. After several attempts, it packaged without errors, but the obfuscated output doesn't have any classes in my project. The directory structure, jar libraries, and other configuration files are all included. What should I do?
my build configration in pom.xml
    <build>
        <finalName>hello</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>       
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>       
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>       
                <executions>          
                    <execution>             
                        <phase>package</phase>             
                        <goals>                
                            <goal>proguard</goal>             
                        </goals>          
                    </execution>       
                </executions>       
                <configuration>          
                    <proguardVersion>7.4.2</proguardVersion>          
                    <injar>${project.build.finalName}.war</injar>
                    <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-obf.war</outjar>        
                    <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>          
                    <proguardInclude>${project.basedir}/proguard.cfg</proguardInclude>          
                    <libs>             
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/lib/jrt-fs.jar</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.base.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.compiler.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.datatransfer.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.desktop.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.instrument.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.logging.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.management.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.management.rmi.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.naming.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.prefs.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.rmi.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.scripting.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.se.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.security.jgss.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.security.sasl.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.smartcardio.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.sql.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.sql.rowset.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.transaction.xa.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.xml.crypto.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/java.xml.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.accessibility.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.aot.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.attach.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.charsets.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.compiler.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.crypto.cryptoki.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.crypto.ec.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.crypto.mscapi.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.dynalink.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.editpad.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.hotspot.agent.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.httpserver.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.internal.ed.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.internal.jvmstat.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.internal.le.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.internal.opt.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.internal.vm.ci.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.internal.vm.compiler.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.jartool.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.javadoc.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.jcmd.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.jconsole.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.jdeps.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.jdi.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.jdwp.agent.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.jlink.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.jshell.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.jsobject.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.jstatd.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.localedata.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.management.agent.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.management.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.naming.dns.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.naming.rmi.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.net.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.pack.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.rmic.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.scripting.nashorn.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.sctp.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.security.auth.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.security.jgss.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.unsupported.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.xml.dom.jmod</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home.openjdk11}/jmods/jdk.zipfs.jmod</lib>
                    </libs>       
                </configuration>       
                <dependencies>          
                    <dependency>             
                        <groupId>com.guardsquare</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>7.4.2</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.guardsquare</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-core</artifactId>
                        <version>9.1.3</version>
                    </dependency>   
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>   
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>          
                    <execution>             
                        <goals>                
                            <goal>repackage</goal>             
                        </goals>             
                        <configuration>                
                            <mainClass>com.hello.HelloApplication</mainClass>             
                        </configuration>          
                    </execution>       
                </executions> 
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

and proguard configration
-dontshrink 
-dontoptimize 
-useuniqueclassmembernames 
-adaptclassstrings 
-dontnote
-ignorewarnings 
-dontwarn
-verbose

-keep class ch.qos.logback.** { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keep class com.profesorfalken.wmi4java.** { *; }
-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class lombok.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class java.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer

and console log after running "mvn clean package"
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [barcode-print-server-websocket] in [C:\workspace\hello-project\target\hello]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Building war: C:\workspace\hello-project\target\hello.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] proguard:2.6.1:proguard (default) @ barcode-print-server-websocket ---
[INFO] execute ProGuard [-injars, 'C:\workspace\hello-project\target\hello.war'(!META-INF/maven/**), -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-websocket\2.5.4\spring-boot-starter-websocket-2.5.4.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.5.4\spring-boot-starter-web-2.5.4.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.5.4\spring-boot-starter-json-2.5.4.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.12.4\jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.12.4\jackson-annotations-2.12.4.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.12.4\jackson-core-2.12.4.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.12.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.12.4.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.12.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.12.4.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.12.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.12.4.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.9\spring-web-5.3.9.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.9\spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.9\spring-aop-5.3.9.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.9\spring-expression-5.3.9.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-messaging\5.3.9\spring-messaging-5.3.9.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.9\spring-beans-5.3.9.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-websocket\5.3.9\spring-websocket-5.3.9.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.9\spring-context-5.3.9.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.5.4\spring-boot-starter-2.5.4.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.5.4\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.5.4.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.5\logback-classic-1.2.5.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.5\logback-core-1.2.5.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.14.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.14.1\log4j-api-2.14.1.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.32\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.28\snakeyaml-1.28.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.32\slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.9\spring-core-5.3.9.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.9\spring-jcl-5.3.9.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.5.4\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.5.4.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.52\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.52\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.52.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.52\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.52.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.5.4\spring-boot-devtools-2.5.4.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.5.4\spring-boot-2.5.4.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.5.4\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.20\lombok-1.18.20.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\com\profesorfalken\WMI4Java\1.6.3\WMI4Java-1.6.3.jar', -libraryjars, 'C:\maven\repository\com\profesorfalken\jPowerShell\3.0\jPowerShell-3.0.jar', -outjars, 'C:\workspace\hello-project\target\hello-obf.war', -include, 'C:\workspace\hello-project\proguard.cfg', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/lib/jrt-fs.jar', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.base.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.compiler.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.datatransfer.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.desktop.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.instrument.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.logging.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.management.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.management.rmi.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.naming.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.prefs.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.rmi.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.scripting.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.se.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.security.jgss.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.security.sasl.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.smartcardio.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.sql.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.sql.rowset.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.transaction.xa.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.xml.crypto.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/java.xml.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.accessibility.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.aot.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.attach.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.charsets.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.compiler.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.crypto.cryptoki.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.crypto.ec.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.crypto.mscapi.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.dynalink.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.editpad.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.hotspot.agent.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.httpserver.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.internal.ed.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.internal.jvmstat.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.internal.le.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.internal.opt.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.internal.vm.ci.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.internal.vm.compiler.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.jartool.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.javadoc.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.jcmd.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.jconsole.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.jdeps.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.jdi.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.jdwp.agent.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.jlink.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.jshell.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.jsobject.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.jstatd.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.localedata.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.management.agent.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.management.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.naming.dns.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.naming.rmi.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.net.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.pack.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.rmic.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.scripting.nashorn.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.sctp.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.security.auth.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.security.jgss.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.unsupported.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.xml.dom.jmod', -libraryjars, 'c:\jdk-11/jmods/jdk.zipfs.jmod', -printmapping, 'C:\workspace\hello-project\target\proguard_map.txt', -printseeds, 'C:\workspace\hello-project\target\proguard_seed.txt']
[INFO] proguard jar: [C:\maven\repository\com\guardsquare\proguard-base\7.4.2\proguard-base-7.4.2.jar]
 [proguard] ProGuard, version 7.4.2
 [proguard] Reading input...
 [proguard] Reading program war [C:\workspace\hello-project\target\hello.war] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-websocket\2.5.4\spring-boot-starter-websocket-2.5.4.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.5.4\spring-boot-starter-web-2.5.4.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.5.4\spring-boot-starter-json-2.5.4.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.12.4\jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.12.4\jackson-annotations-2.12.4.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.12.4\jackson-core-2.12.4.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.12.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.12.4.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.12.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.12.4.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.12.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.12.4.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.9\spring-web-5.3.9.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.9\spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.9\spring-aop-5.3.9.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.9\spring-expression-5.3.9.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-messaging\5.3.9\spring-messaging-5.3.9.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.9\spring-beans-5.3.9.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-websocket\5.3.9\spring-websocket-5.3.9.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.9\spring-context-5.3.9.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.5.4\spring-boot-starter-2.5.4.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.5.4\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.5.4.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.5\logback-classic-1.2.5.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.5\logback-core-1.2.5.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.14.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.14.1\log4j-api-2.14.1.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.32\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.28\snakeyaml-1.28.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.32\slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.9\spring-core-5.3.9.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.9\spring-jcl-5.3.9.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.5.4\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.5.4.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.52\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.52\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.52.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.52\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.52.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.5.4\spring-boot-devtools-2.5.4.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.5.4\spring-boot-2.5.4.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.5.4\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.20\lombok-1.18.20.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\com\profesorfalken\WMI4Java\1.6.3\WMI4Java-1.6.3.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\maven\repository\com\profesorfalken\jPowerShell\3.0\jPowerShell-3.0.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jar [c:\jdk-11\lib\jrt-fs.jar] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.base.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.compiler.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.datatransfer.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.desktop.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.instrument.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.logging.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.management.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.management.rmi.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.naming.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.prefs.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.rmi.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.scripting.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.se.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.security.jgss.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.security.sasl.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.smartcardio.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.sql.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.sql.rowset.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.transaction.xa.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.xml.crypto.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\java.xml.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.accessibility.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.aot.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.attach.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.charsets.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.compiler.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.crypto.cryptoki.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.crypto.ec.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.crypto.mscapi.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.dynalink.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.editpad.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.hotspot.agent.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.httpserver.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.internal.ed.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.internal.jvmstat.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.internal.le.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.internal.opt.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.internal.vm.ci.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.internal.vm.compiler.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.jartool.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.javadoc.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.jcmd.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.jconsole.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.jdeps.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.jdi.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.jdwp.agent.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.jlink.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.jshell.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.jsobject.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.jstatd.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.localedata.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.management.agent.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.management.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.naming.dns.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.naming.rmi.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.net.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.pack.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.rmic.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.scripting.nashorn.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.sctp.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.security.auth.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.security.jgss.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.unsupported.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.xml.dom.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Reading library jmod [c:\jdk-11\jmods\jdk.zipfs.jmod] (filtered)
 [proguard] Initializing...
 [proguard] Ignoring unused library classes...
 [proguard]   Original number of library classes:              31272
 [proguard]   Final number of library classes:                 31272
 [proguard] Marking classes and class members to be kept...
 [proguard] Printing kept classes, fields, and methods...
 [proguard] Inlining subroutines...
 [proguard] Obfuscating...
 [proguard] Printing mapping to [C:\workspace\hello-project\target\proguard_map.txt]...
 [proguard]   Number of obfuscated classes:                  18
 [proguard]   Number of obfuscated fields:                   26
 [proguard]   Number of obfuscated methods:                  42
 [proguard] Preverifying...
 [proguard] Writing output...
 [proguard] Preparing output war [C:\workspace\hello-project\target\hello-obf.war] (filtered)
 [proguard]   Copying resources from program war [C:\workspace\hello-project\target\hello.war] (filtered)
[INFO] 
[INFO] spring-boot:2.5.4:repackage (repackage) @ hello-project ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] 
[INFO] spring-boot:2.5.4:repackage (default) @ hello-project ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:13 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-06-13T16:20:37-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

I also tried deleting the repackage of the spring-boot-maven-plugin, but the result was the same.
